# How to limit or descripe object posibilities

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, dll

I have got a very special problem. 
I got an xsd schema and generate classes from them. Just like xsd.exe from Microsoft. Now i want to use this generated file as dll. So far so good.

Example Code:

```
    public enum UnnamedChoice115 {
         UNDEFINIERT, 
         nur_Zustandsanzeige, 
         Zustandsanzeige_und_Steuerstelle, 
         Zustandsanzeige_und_Steuerstelle_AUTO, 
    }

    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    public class ctyp_PLS_Anbindung_InOutByte
    {
       private object objgenField;
       [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("nur_Zustandsanzeige", typeof(ctyp_PLS_A), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
       [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Zustandsanzeige_und_Steuerstelle", typeof(ctyp_PLS_B), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
       [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Zustandsanzeige_und_Steuerstelle_AUTO", typeof(ctyp_PLS_C), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
       [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("objIdentifier")]
       public object objGen
       {
          get { return objgenField; }
          set { objgenField = value;}
       }

       private UnnamedChoice115 objidentifierField;
       [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
       public UnnamedChoice115 objIdentifier
       {
          get { return objidentifierField; }
          set { objidentifierField = value; }
       }
    }
```

You will see the property objGen is type of object, but the serialization allows three different types 'ctyp_PLS_A' , 'ctyp_PLS_B' or 'ctyp_PLS_C'.
How to get this info to the user of the compiled dll?
It is realy hard to implement a basetype for this, so i want a simple description within the dll that says, "hey programmer, you can only use these types with this property". More like an integrated usage info. The best thing is compiler support, but... if, i dont know how.

Comment: Why not just give the users the Schema?  The website for the schema usually has a document explaining all the options.  If you click on the URL you may be able to get the document for the types.  So URL have the document and others don't.

Comment: Good point, but this is the way i do now. I want it a bit faster.

Comment: I was answering the following question (not your code) : How to get this info to the user of the compiled dll?